# How can I find a lost 401K from a past employer?

Tags: united-states, 401k

I've been rather sloppy about keeping track of 401(k)s from previous employers. There are two that I've lost track of completely. One is from an employer that no longer seems to exist, and the other employer has been bought out and doesn't seem to want to return my calls.

I don't recall anything about which financial companies managed the 401Ks, nor can I find any statements from them.

How can I track them down so I can get them rolled over into my current one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Employee Benefits Security Administration within the US Department of Labor is tasked with keeping track of pension and 401K programs. The even have a website to search for [abandoned plans](http://askebsa.dol.gov/abandonedplansearch/):

> it helps participants and others find out whether a particular plan is in the process of being, or has been, terminated and the name of the Qualified Termination Administrator (QTA) responsible for the termination.

The Employee Benefits Security Administration discuss all types of details regarding retirement programs. This document [What You Should Know About Your Retirement Plan](http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/publications/wyskapr.html) has a lot of details including this:

> If your former employer has gone out of business, arrangements should
>   have been made so a plan official remains responsible for the payment
>   of benefits and other plan business. If you are entitled to benefits
>   and are unable to contact the plan administrator, contact EBSA
>   electronically at askebsa.dol.gov or by calling toll free at
>   1-866-444-3272.

There are also [EBSA offices](http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/aboutebsa/org_chart.html#section13) spread thought the United States

Comment: Thanks. No luck with the search form in the first link, but I'll read everything on the second link and go from there.