# How to locate a lost 401k that I can not find?

Tags: united-states, 401k

I never collected from an old 401k that I invested in through an old employer about 10 years ago. I recently contacted the old employer to inquire about it and they told me to get a hold of Principal Financial who had it last. So I did! Only to be told that in 2010 that it was rolled over into an IRA, but there isn't any more information. How can I find it? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find a lost 401K from a past employer?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33656/how-can-i-find-a-lost-401k-from-a-past-employer)

Comment: After reading that link more, I don't think it's an actual duplicate, as the poster knows where the 401k was, they just don't know what happened to it. There may still be some useful links in there though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming nothing [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/33656/how-can-i-find-a-lost-401k-from-a-past-employer?rq=1) helps, here are some thoughts.

First, If Principal Financial knows the 401k was rolled over to an IRA, then it must have been a custodian-to-custodian transfer, which means they need to know who the recipient custodian was, so I'd call them back and push a little harder.

Next, they couldn't have just created an IRA out of thin air and moved some money into it without some paperwork and signatures from you, so you should have copies of that paperwork. Principal may also still have archived copies of that paperwork, that they may be able to provide to you, although they'll probably charge for that service.

Also, there would have been tax reporting around the rollover. For the year the rollover occurred in, you would have received a 1099-R and 5498. The 1099-R would have to have been reported on your federal (and possibly state) income tax for that year. It *may* be possible to obtain copies of old 1099-R's from the IRS, maybe call them and ask.

In subsequent years, you should have received at least a year-end statement.

If you don't have any of that, and contacting Principal and the IRS don't help, then I'm not sure there's much that anyone can do to help you. As far as I know, there's no "universal clearinghouse" for IRAs, and there are a *lot* of IRA custodians.

I would expect you to receive a year-end statement from the custodian for 2015 sometime in early 2016, so maybe just wait for (and watch for) that.

And take this as an object lesson that you need to keep better track of your finances. No one's going to do it for you (unless you pay them a bunch of money).

Comment: IRS Form 4506T has an option to request transcript of W-2,1098,1099,5498 'information returns' which 'may' be available 'for up to 10 years', 'most[ly] processed within 10 business days'.  And you might be able to request online; they recently announced they're reopening the Get Transcript application after shutting it down for a year due to hacking, but I don't know if all options are included.

Comment: They CAN absolutely create an IRA out of thin air without Robert's signature. These are usually created for dormant accounts that have been forced out of plans. I work for a TPA and we usually use a company called Penchecks. They hold dormant accounts in custody in an IRA in the name of the participant/beneficiary and "use their best efforts" to locate said participant and return their money. Kind of like a reverse debt collector. Of course they take a few points every year for their service. Principal should absolutely have a record of the distribution though.

Comment: "then I'm not sure there's much that anyone can do to help you" The downvote is me. This is incorrect. There are several companies that hold dormant retirement plan balances, and the PBGC will help participants and beneficiaries find lost balances. [http://www.pbgc.gov/](http://www.pbgc.gov/)

Answer (score 1):

Principal has probably distributed your money to a company that holds dormant retirement plan account balances. I work for a third-party administrator and we usually use a company called Penchecks. They receive dormant accounts and try to locate the people they belong to. They don't do this for free though, so the sooner you find your account the better. Principal would have to keep a record of where they sent your money, although I don't know for how long they are required to keep that record. For example, doctors are only required to keep records for 7 years.

The PBGC will help you find your lost balance. They are a gov't agency that protects retirement plan participants. They have a search engine for this kind of thing: http://search.pbgc.gov/mp/

Also https://www.unclaimedretirementbenefits.com/ is a registry of unclaimed retirement plan benefits.